# How to know if a ImageView has changed?

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, drawable

I have this Android Studio app  which has an ImageView with a drawable on it, then I click it and it opens whether the camera or gallery, you pick the picture and then ImageView changes to the picture the user choose.

I am using this in a Create Account Activity, and when the user clicks the Create Account Button, It sends you a Warning if you haven't filled up all the fields, but, in the ImageView how can I check if it has a new picture?
This is how my code is:

```
  btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            city = editTextCity.getText().toString().trim();
            email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            birthday = editTextBirthday.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!email.isEmpty() && !name.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !birthday.isEmpty() && !city.isEmpty()) {

                if (Here is supposed where i want to check if the imageView has changed)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "You havent choosed a image yet",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "You filled up all the fields",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "there are some fields unfilled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you actually want to.  What you want to do instead is check if the user has selected a new picture.  Have a boolean value pictureSelected in your activity.  Set it to false at startup.  When you change the drawable in the imageView, set it to true.  Then just check pictureSelected in your if statement here.

Answer (score 2):

Before the user chooses a picture, save the current `drawable` of the `ImageView` and in the `onClick` compare the old one with the current

before choosing an image:

```
Drawable oldDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
```

in the `onClick` method:

```
if (imageView.getDrawable() == oldDrawable)
      {

           Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "You havent choosed a image yet",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

you can also use `imageView.getDrawable() == null` to check if the imageView doesn't have any attached image beforehand